# Simplify: $[ (A_1 \cap B_1) \times A_2 \times \dotsb \times A_n ] \cup \dotsb \cup [ A_1 \times \dotsb \times A_{n-1} \times (A_n \cap B_n) ]$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I've just started studying Measure Theory. I was a little bit stuck on simplifying a set theoretic expression when I tried to prove a little problem from my reference book. Here I pose my problem in a general set theoretic manner:

> Given two finite families of indexed sets $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^n$ and $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^n$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Can we simplify
> $$ \tag{1}
> \Big[ (A_1 \cap B_1) \times A_2 \times \dotsb \times A_n \Big] \cup \dotsb \cup
> \Big[ A_1 \times \dotsb \times A_{n-1} \times (A_n \cap B_n) \Big] 
> $$
> into a form of large union operation?

Here is my attempt:

> I directly put the large union operation into the following expression:
> $$ \tag{2}
> \bigcup_{k=1}^n \left[ \left( \prod_{\alpha=1}^{k - 1} A_\alpha \right) \times \big( A_k
> \cap B_k \big) \times \left( \prod_{\beta = k + 1}^{n} A_\beta \right) \right]
> $$
> My concern is, when $k = 1$, we have
> $$ \tag{3}
> \left( \prod_{\alpha = 1}^0 A_\alpha \right) \times (A_1 \cap B_1) \times
> \left( \prod_{\beta = 2}^n A_\beta \right)
> $$
> and when $k = n$ we have
> $$ \tag{4}
> \left( \prod_{\alpha = 1}^{n-1} A_\alpha \right) \times (A_n \cap B_n) \times
> \left( \prod_{\beta = n+1}^n A_\beta \right)
> $$
> within the square braces, each of which is syntactically error. I presume
> $$ \tag{5}
> \prod_{\alpha = 1}^0 A_\alpha = \prod_{\varnothing} A_\alpha
> $$
> and
> $$ \tag{6}
> \prod_{\beta = n+1}^n A_\beta = \prod_{\varnothing} A_\beta
> $$
> and hence expression $(2)$ is precisely equal to expression $(1)$.

My big question is: $\textbf{are these presumptions allowed?}$ If it's not the case, then is there any better solution instead of writing down expression $(1)$?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Generally an empty product is taken to be the neutral element for this operation. For the cartesian product there is no neutral product, but we can just invent a formal neutral element, and all is fine.

A different simplification could be simply:
$$ \{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in A_1\times\ldots\times A_n\mid \exists k: a_k\in B_k\}$$

EDIT: Since you are specifying measure theory, maybe you also want to simplify this to disjoint union? Like
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^n \left(\prod_{l<k}A_l\setminus B_l\right)\times (A_k\cap B_k)\times\prod_{l>k}A_l$$

Comment: I see. Initially, I was not sure whether my invention was allowed. But I get it clear from your answer and from my search at other place. Your simplification in set builder notation is very good and clear. I could've made use of it anyway. Thanks.

Thanks again for the latest suggestion. I'll take it under consideration. It'll be useful once I deal with the main topics in Measure Theory. At the moment, I am still reading and working on an introductory topic (about the measure of elementary sets of R^n).

Comment: I am using 'An Introduction to Measure Theory' by Terrence Tao (which I directly download from his blog). 
To be honest, I have no formal university education background in math (I have a bachelor degree in Engineering), but I really am interested in pure math, so I study pure math by myself.

Comment: Okay. In measure theory one often wants to have unions of disjoint sets, because then (under certain limitations) the measure of the union is the sum of the measures.